# How to sort Twitter friends / followers by date followed?

Tags: php, sorting, twitter

I want to display Twitter users in the order in which they followed me.

I can get a list of my followers by using this Twitter API call

```
https://api.twitter.com/1/followers/ids.json?screen_name=edent
```

This returns a list of IDs which are **sorted** by when they followed me:

```
574597584,531113272,787166,1060121,
etc
```

I then have to call *user/lookup* to get the data on all the users

```
https://api.twitter.com/1/users/lookup.xml?user_id=574597584,531113272,787166,...
```

Here's the problem - users/lookup is **unsorted**. Every time I call it, I get the users back in a different order.

What the most efficient way to sort *user/lookup* into the **same order** as *follower/ids* using PHP?

Comment: Can't you use the first 'ordered' result to access the second result set in that order?

Comment: Do you mean walk through the 2nd array looking to see if 
  a[$i]->user->id == 123456
And then repeating? Seems rather inefficient. Especially if it's an array of 3,200 users.

Comment: Even if it were inefficient, it's probably not even the slowest part of the process -- I suspect the API call will represent a larger chunk of time. That said, you could probably use xpath for the lookup, and that would be reasonably fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per ilanco's comment, here's how to order Twitter friends / followers

```
// Get all the user ID of the friends   
$request_ids = "https://api.twitter.com/1/friends/ids.json?screen_name={$user}";
```

That returns a JSON list of all the IDs in order

They need to be put in the form 1,2,3,4 to send use users/lookup

```
// Construct the request
$request = "https://api.twitter.com/1/users/lookup.xml?user_id=".$user_ids;
```

Then, walk through the array of users, lookup the user ID from the first array, place the user in a new array according to the order in the first array

```
$sortedUsers = array();

foreach ($users as $user) {
    $user_id = $user->id;       
    $key = array_search($user_id, $ids);
    $sortedUsers[$key] = $user;
}
```

Sort the new array by key

```
ksort($sortedUsers);
```

It's fairly crude, but it works.